# Run python script on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, subprocess

I am trying to run a simple Python script which runs the `ipconfig /all` command as a proof of concept.

You can find it below:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run

my_command = "ipconfig /all"
result = run(my_command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(result.stdout, result.stderr)
```

But I didn't suceed to run it, I tryed both with the command line and by clicking on it but it open a cmd window for 1 second, and then close it so I cannot even read it.

Edit: I am using Python 3.7 and my script is called `ipconfig.py`

Comment: How exactly did you try to run it with the command line?

Comment: I tried to run `python ipconfig.py`

Comment: Where? And what happened then?

Comment: You're missing `shell=True` (though a better approach is to proceed with `shell=False` and instead use `my_command=['ipconfig', '/all']`)

Comment: In the folder containing my script, using powershell, the output is the following: *python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.* but as I would like to give this script to someone that don't know programming language nor command line I would like to be able to run it by clicking on it

Comment: The person you'd like to give this to (who does not know programming language nor command line) -- do they have python and any dependencies installed?

Comment: Make sure you've added python to your PATH, and if you have and it's still not working, open a new command line (cmd doesn't recognize environment changes made while it's open)

Comment: @DavidZemens Not yet but I am actually facing this issue on my environment not his one.

Comment: @JulioCezarSilva I will check how to add python to my PATH thanks

Comment: @Ced You've probably found it already, but anything like what's said in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/143121) is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working good.
The problem is that the cmd closes the window too fast and you can't see the result.
Just add a command to wait for your interaction before closing the window.

You can add this at the end of your code:

```
input("Press Enter to finish...")
```

Or pause the execution after completion:

```
import time
```

[at the end of the code pause for 5 seconds....]

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `input("Press Enter to finish...")` Works and fixed the issue while clicking thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your problem is not related to the script itself, but rather to *Python* interpreter invocation. Check [[Python 3.Docs]: How do I run a Python program under Windows?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows). 
 A general approach would be to:

- Open a *cmd* (*PS*) window in your script directory
- Launch *Python* (using its full path: check [[Python 3.Docs]: Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) for more details) on your module (e.g.):

  ```bat
  "C:\Program Files\Python37-64\python.exe" ipconfig.py
  ```

Of course, there are many ways to improve things, like adding its installation directory in *%PATH%* (if not already there) in order to avoid specifying its full path every time <sup>***1***</sup>, but take one step at a time.

On the script side: check [[Python 3.Docs]: subprocess.**run**(*args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (and the examples):

- Pass the arguments as a list:

  ```py
  my_command = ["ipconfig", "/all"]
  ```
- You might also want to check the command termination status (`result.returncode`)

---

***1***: If you didn't check *Add Python 3.7 to PATH* when installing it (check image from 2<sup>nd</sup> *URL*), you have to add *Python*'s path (***C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37***) manually. There are many resources on the web, here are 3:

- [[SuperUser]: How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)
- [[Geek University]: Add Python to the Windows Path](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path)
- [[RaspberryPi.Projects]: Is Python in your PATH?](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/5)